# How to create a copy of a document before saving with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document which user updates via web UI. I want to create a copy of the document and save it to the same collection before new changes are saved.

Here is the hook I am trying to consume:

```
PrototypeSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const protoCopy = new Prototype(proto.toObject())
  protoCopy.save()

  this.lastUpdateDate = new Date()
  next()
})
```

This causes infinite pre-save hook to be executed. How do I make a copy of the document and save both new version (as the same document) and previous one (as a new document)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [pre-save middleware documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes), it does not run when updating a document but when inserting. For this you should use the pre-update. However, I am pretty sure that when the middleware runs the document already contains the changes so saving a copy of that document would be duplicating the updated document, and not saving a copy of the original document. I think the easier way may be to save the new document (with the old data) at the same place (controller or whatever) where you are updating the original document:

```
var originalId = "foo";
var changes = {foo: "bar"};

Prototype.findById(originalId, function(err, original){
    if (err) return { err };
    Prototype.insert(original, function(err){
        if (err) return { err };
        Prototype.findAndUpdate({_id: originalId}, changes, { new: true }, function(err, updated){
            return { err, updated };
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:

About what I said (and the documentation says) about pre-save middleware not running when updating a document, I just thought I'm not sure if this depends on the version of Mongoose you're using. In any case, my code would work with any version.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @virgiliogm! I already thought about moving this logic from hooks to just the controller where I call the document update. I think, the best and clearest way is to do this there.